# What is the purpose of making a project in Sublime?

Tags: editor, settings, project, sublimetext3

I was reading a [blog](http://www.matthewlang.net/2013/10/15/getting-to-know-projects-in-sublime-text/) to better understanding the purpose of making a project for sublime (or any editor):

> When you save your code as a project you end up with two files. The
>   first is the project file which contains references to folders for
>   your project, project based settings and build commands for your
>   project. The second file is the workspace. This is simply a file that
>   tracks what layout you're currently using and what files you have open
>   in each pane. Using the workspace file means that you can switch to
>   another project, do some work and then switchback to your original
>   project knowing that the layout and files you had open will be
>   restored back to the state you left them in. Handy.

So seems like there's 2 reasons? 1. is to save settings and 2. is to save the current layout of the files and folders you have already opened? I see reason 2 to be nice, but not really super important. What are some of the settings in reason 1 that's important to keep in between projects? What is a build command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simply have to follow different coding standards for different customers, e.g. indentation rules, so its handy that you can set these rules on a per project basis.

A build system let's you run or compile code directly from Sublime Text.